# Problem identifying the $S^1\times\lbrace 1 \rbrace$ space

Tags: general-topology

I think the title is self explanatory. I thought that $S^1\times\lbrace 1 \rbrace$ was the pinched space but right now I'm not that sure anymore.

Comment: It is a circle hovering in the air.

Comment: Than why not call it just $S^1$? I'm really struggling with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a topological space, it is homeomorphic to $S^1$. Indeed, the map $S^1 \to S^1 \times \{1\}$ defined by $x \mapsto (x, 1)$ is a homeomorphism.

As for its position in $\Bbb R^3$, it is a circle with centre at $(0, 0, 1)$ with radius $1$ lying on the plane $z = 1$.